# What threats do trusted browser events protect against?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm trying to understand what sort of different security problems or other problems trusted events protect against - what was the purpose adding it to the event properties?

Comment: Trusted browser events are essentially events that occurred naturally. For example, a trusted click event was actually generated by clicking. Manufactured events, on the other hand, are not trusted. For example, it's possible for Javascript to create and emit a click event but it will be flagged as untrusted. It's not possible for Javascript to manufacture a trusted event.

Comment: So why would the browser care about that? What is the application?

Comment: I'm not sure of the rational behind it. It's in the W3C spec but they don't offer anything beyond a technical description. [This](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/cEJvjWg9bqg) offers one possibility relating to extensions and notes that it's of limited usefulness.